# Webix control localization Label Caption in Arabic language

Tags: webix

can we print label caption in other language like Arabic, Hindi?

```
webix.i18n.locales["en-US"].text = {
 labels:{"test": "AAAA",}
};
webix.i18n.setLocale("en-US");

webix.ready(function(){
view:"text"
      label:"test"
  }],   
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create/modify a locale and then give its labels to components, you probably should do something like this: https://snippet.webix.com/gosx5k51

After `setLocale` calls the labels will be taken from the related locale.

BTW Webix already has 10 free and about 350 PRO edition locales (Arabic and Hindi included) with all labels of components.

Comment: @MurugesanK by the way, Webix has a framework that allows splitting app code into modules, separating UI from logic and has a set of plugins for common tasks, e.g. for localization, which is I think what suits your case very much. https://webix.gitbook.io/webix-jet/part-ii-webix-jet-in-details/plugins#locale-plugin